# no execution (rights) at home / can not make /home executable (exec) when using encrypted (LUKS) / mounted home

Tags: permissions, mount, encryption, luks, execute-command

The issue:

**I do not have / lost executable rights in my /home**.
Which is quite devastating for TOR onion use.
This pops up on increasing number of machines with Ubuntu 20.xxSome new set up and some worked with existing exec rights before .

Situation:

- sometimes this occurs irreversible on runing systems.
- The execute rights for the file and directory and "/home" are given and OK.
- **/home is a mount because it is encrypted /  a LUKS partition**.
- The **"exec" IS given in fstab**
  (`/dev/mapper/luks-12345   /home ext4      exec,rw,users    0 2`) but
  it is IGNORED.
- Doing a **rw re-mount is successful**  and used for workaround: from /etc/systemd/system/ start service doing "mount -o remount,rw /dev/mapper/luks-12345  /home/"  This shows it is not an issue of missing exec rights with files or directories. This workaround is ugly and only cures symptoms.

Mount is reported as:

```
/home     /dev/mapper/luks-12345 ext4  rw,nosuid,nodev,**noexec**,relatime
```

although set as exec in fstab.

Question:

- **Why is the mount option "exec" ignored** (on an increasing number of machines)?

Example executed in ~:

```
$ ./myscript.sh
bash: ./myscript.sh: Keine Berechtigung   (translate: no rights)

same old script after rw remount: 
 - just executing -
```

Remarks:

Setup of encrypted /home is shown here (use TOR; German only): http://mutant21.onastroidst6krpn.onion/schweinekraftland/Verschluesseln01/Verschluesselung_nachtraeglich_umsetzen.htm
All file systems are ext4.
It appears on several machines. Earliest identified OS rel. is Ubuntu 20.04 since mid of 2020.

mount version:  util-linux 2.36  libmount 2.36.0

Looks to me like a bug, no doc found: If you remove the mount option "users" the problem will not occur. This must have changed mid 2020 since it definitely worked early 2020 to have option "users" and a mount with applied exec rights. Does not explain why "exec" option is just ignored when used in fstab the regular way.

Addendum:

mount version 2.34 does not show the error. Using mount version 2.36 causes the error, reproducible.
Does not explain the bug but it explains the timeline of occurence.

Comment: Can you give us an example of a workflow you aren't able to complete and give us details like error messages that you are receiving?

Comment: there are no error messages. Trying to execute a command allocated in file system /home is refused due to missing rights.  Nothing special.

Comment: "*Trying to execute a command allocated in file system /home is refused due to missing rights."* -- will you provide the specifics of *that* example?

Comment: example added using simple shell script (worked before, works when issue is circumvented); GUI icons just die silent :-\

Comment: To debug your script, we really need to see the whole script. It would be even better from a diagnostic standpoint if you can run each line of the script manually in the terminal and then post the terminal output of each line.  That's what I mean by posting the specifics/details.

Comment: debug script??? You misunderstood it 100%. This is not about a script. Read the findmnt line!! The issue is not about scripts...  it is about MOUNT !

Comment: Even with all the info you provided, I'm not confident that you've identified the problem. You might be right, but it could be something else as well.  I'm asking for more diagnostic information, like error messages, which are generally extremely helpful in not only identifying the problem, but also the solution. If you don't want to post the information, I still encourage you to run each line of your script in the terminal one-by-one.  More info can only help.

Comment: if all you have is a hammer, each problem must be a nail. @Nmath we better stop this discussion now.